# .NET 5 SDK not found - OS X

Tags: .net, macos, .net-core, .net-5

I am trying to load a solution full of .NET 5.0 projects that works fine on Win10. However, after upgrading from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5.0 SDK, my MacBook Pro is no longer able to load the projects.

macOS Catalina - 10.15.7 (19H524) - Intel i7, not the M1 :)

**Error message (Jetbrains Rider):**

```
[MSB4236] The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.
```

**Error message (Visual Studio for Mac):**

```
Error: .NET Core 5.0.104 SDK is required to build this application, and is not installed. Install the latest update to the .NET Core 5.0.104 SDK by visiting https://aka.ms/vs/mac/install-netcore5
```

Of course I've already installed .NET 5.0 Runtime and SDK several times ... I've double checked it with following commands:

```
dotnet --version
5.0.104

dotnet --list-sdks
5.0.104 [/usr/local/Cellar/dotnet/5.0.104/libexec/sdk]
```

Content of my PATH variable:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

I've also tried uninstalling dotnet using the dotnet-uninstall-tool .. without success.
Any thoughts are welcome!

Thanks,

**UPDATE:**

Since dotnet-uninstall-tool did not completely remove .NET SDK / RUNTIME from my Mac I've manually deleted all associated files. I've also removed dotnet from my PATH variable. A fresh installation finally solved the problem.

Comment: Is there a DOTNET_HOME environment variable set or other installations in `/usr/local/share/dotnet` that VS/mac's resolution logic maybe also looks into?

Comment: there was no DOTNET_HOME environment variable. But I solved it after removing .NET completely manually from my Mac. See update in post - thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved:**

Since dotnet-uninstall-tool did not completely remove .NET SDK / RUNTIME from my Mac I've manually deleted all associated files. I've also removed dotnet from my PATH variable. A fresh installation finally solved the problem.

Comment: Hi! I suggest moving the solution to the answer content to the answer post so you answer your own question but still preserve the Q&A format. It is perfectly okay and encouraged to answer and accept your own questions.